# How to step-debug assembly binaries with no symbols or sections?

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, x86

Consider the following NASM code:

```
  BITS 32

                org     0x08048000

  ehdr:                                                 ; Elf32_Ehdr
                db      0x7F, "ELF", 1, 1, 1, 0         ;   e_ident
        times 8 db      0
                dw      2                               ;   e_type
                dw      3                               ;   e_machine
                dd      1                               ;   e_version
                dd      _start                          ;   e_entry
                dd      phdr - $$                       ;   e_phoff
                dd      0                               ;   e_shoff
                dd      0                               ;   e_flags
                dw      ehdrsize                        ;   e_ehsize
                dw      phdrsize                        ;   e_phentsize
                dw      1                               ;   e_phnum
                dw      0                               ;   e_shentsize
                dw      0                               ;   e_shnum
                dw      0                               ;   e_shstrndx

  ehdrsize      equ     $ - ehdr

  phdr:                                                 ; Elf32_Phdr
                dd      1                               ;   p_type
                dd      0                               ;   p_offset
                dd      $$                              ;   p_vaddr
                dd      $$                              ;   p_paddr
                dd      filesize                        ;   p_filesz
                dd      filesize                        ;   p_memsz
                dd      5                               ;   p_flags
                dd      0x1000                          ;   p_align

  phdrsize      equ     $ - phdr

  _start:

                xor     eax, eax ;now just return to system with ebx
                inc     eax
                int     0x80


  ; your program here

  filesize      equ     $ - $$
```

How to debug programs structured like this? Most preferrably I'm looking for a GDB solution that would let me step-run the assembly instructions, allowing to preview the registers every step. Here's what happens when I want to set a memory-based breakpoint there:

```
[localhost.localdomain][/tmp] $ gdb ./a.out 
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora (7.5.1-37.fc18)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) break 0x08048054
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
(gdb) list breakpoints
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command to set a breakpoint at a specific address should be `break *0x08048054` in your example. For single-stepping through the binary, you can then use the `stepi` (step instruction) command.

Comment: And you get a register dump with `info registers`.